# Finder: show video thumbnail for all kind of formats/containers

Tags: finder, video

I wish that Finder show video thumbnail for all kind of formats and containers. *.flv doesn't get a preview, some *.mp4 not, *.mov not.

Is this possible? Maybe a video browser in place of Finder? I have Perian installed.

Comment: Can you give some more specifics on your Mac OS? For example, what version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

[Flash Video Viewer](http://www.qlplugins.com/plugins/flash-video-viewer) added thumbnails for flv files and [Flip4Mac](http://www.telestream.net/flip4mac/overview.htm) for wmv files.

I didn't find any way to add support for mkv or other formats. VLC, MPlayerX, Movist, and NicePlayer don't come with Quick Look plugins.

Comment: howto install that Flash Video Viewer?

Comment: Since you already have Perian, just download the zip, move flv.qlgenerator to /Library/QuickLook/, and log out and back in.

Comment: linked site gives 404 (flash video viewer)